# need some help in Abraham twitteroauth class

Tags: php, twitter-oauth

i m learning  how to use twitter from [twitter developer link](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/auth)
on Authenticating Requests with OAuth page i was debugging my code with given procedure

on ***Sending the user to authorization*** section there is written that

> if you are using the callback flow,
> your oauth_callback should have
> received back your oauth_token (the
> same that you sent, your "request
> token") and a field called the
> oauth_verifier. You'll need that for
> the next step.
>
> Here's the response I received:
>
> oauth_token=8ldIZyxQeVrFZXFOZH5tAwj6vzJYuLQpl0WUEYtWc&oauth_verifier=pDNg57prOHapMbhv25RNf75lVRd6JDsni1AJJIDYoTY

my original code is

```
require_once('twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php');
require_once('config.php');

/* Build TwitterOAuth object with client credentials. */
$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);
 
/* Get temporary credentials. */
$request_token = $connection->getRequestToken(OAUTH_CALLBACK);


/* Save temporary credentials to session. */
$_SESSION['oauth_token'] = $token = $request_token['oauth_token'];
$_SESSION['oauth_token_secret'] = $request_token['oauth_token_secret'];
/* If last connection failed don't display authorization link. */
switch ($connection->http_code) {
  case 200:
    /* Build authorize URL and redirect user to Twitter. */
    echo "<br/>Authorize URL:".$url = $connection->getAuthorizeURL($token);
    //header('Location: ' . $url); 
    break;
  default:
    /* Show notification if something went wrong. */
    echo 'Could not connect to Twitter. Refresh the page or try again later.';
}
```

and i m getting Authorize URL:

```
https://twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token=BHqbrTjsPcyvaAsfDwfU149aAcZjtw45nhLBeG1c
```

i m not getting above URL having **oauth_verifier**. please tell me  from where do i see/debug that url??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `oauth_verifier` is a paramater on the URL after the you return from `https://twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token=xyz`. So if you your callback_url is `http://example.com/oauth/complete` after clicking allow on twitter.com you should end up at `http://example.com/oauth/complete?oauth_token=xyz&oauth_verifier=xyz`